# How in Swift to display details of multiple dropped pins

Tags: swift, dictionary, pins

In Swift, I can add map annotation and display details using segue of a dropped pin when the user clicks the "i", but I am having trouble displaying details of multiple dropped pins using segue; unlike ViewTable no index is involved here. How do I do that?

Comment: The user can only tap one "i" so where does this "multiple" notion come from?

Answer (score 0):

Can this give you some hint?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, 
         calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    //get the annotation ,maybe you need cast the type
    // let anno = view.annotation
    //performSegue here

}
```

Comment: I am already doing this and it does show the details, but my problem is it only shows the details of the last dropped pin. How do I make it pass details of the tapped pin?

Comment: Have you passed the selected annotation's info or something to the detail viewController

Comment: I am using this: self.mapItemData = localSearchResponse?.mapItems.last to assign search data to the pin, and passing the info to the segue, it works well for a single pin but don't know how to assign this for multiple pins. mapItemData is MKMapItem

Comment: You should pass the selected mapItemData instead of the last one

Comment: How is that done, I am not familiar with this part of code.

Comment: can you post the viewForAnnotation method?